# How to fetch cpu utilization of a particular process in linux

Tags: linux

I have used following command to fetch the CPU utilization of a process. It is giving result, but it is not coming out. I have used following command.

```
top | grep <processname>
```

I just want to put this in a loop and I will insert sleep in the code so that I can fetch the value in regular intervals

Answer (score 3):

Use top's batch mode, eg.

```
top -b -n1 | grep processname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
while [ 1 ]; do top -n 1 | grep something; sleep 1; done
```

Use the `-n` option of top:

```
-n
    Number of iterations. Update the display this number of times and then exit.
```